# Essential range of a function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $A_f$ be the set of all averages $\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\intop_{E}\,f\,d\mu$

where $E$ is of positive measure. What is the relationship between $A_f$ and $\mathbb{R}_f$? Is $A_f$ always closed?

Are there measures $\mu$ such that $A_f$ is convex for every $f\in L^\infty (\mu)$? Are there measure $\mu$ such that $A_f$ fails to convex for some $f\in L^\infty (\mu)$?

My guess is that $A_f\subset R_f$ and it is closed. But I am not sure if it is convex???

Answer (score 1):

Answers.

a. The essential range is not necessarily achieved by averages. For examples if $f(x)=x$,
$x\in [0,1]$, then the values 0 and 1 are not achieved by $A_f$.

b. Indeed the range of $A_f$ is not necessarily convex. Let $\mu=\delta_0+\delta_1$,
then the only values it achieves are 
$f(0)$, $f(1)$ and $\frac{1}{2}\big(f(0)+f(1)\big)$.

It is convex in the case of Lebesgue measure on an open subset of a Euclidean space.

Comment: The last statement probably comes from the fact (see e.g. Rudin's "Functional analysis") that the range of a non-atomic measure is convex, doesn't it?

Comment: I was not aware of it. I can only show it for the Lebesgue measure. Let me check.